# Using Images and videos in android application(Sqlite blob?)

Tags: android, image, sqlite, video

I'm developing and an application that uses a sqlite database, and I'm having trouble to store images in database, I read a lot of examples, but not working here, can someone tell me the best way to store images in SQLite?
(and then I'll need to store movies as well..)

In the future I'll have to develop a backoffice so the company can add/change/delete items in the db.

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this does not exactly answer your question:

I'd not bother storing those huge blobs in sqlite, but rather store them on file system and only store the file names/paths in sqlite.
This will save you from the hassle of putting the stuff in the DB and manipulation of files (create, delete, list) is relatively easy through `java.io.File` and `FileInputStream` etc.

See e.g. [PicHelper](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/helper/PicHelper.java) as a class that deals with storing / loading data in/from files.

Comment: thanks, this project will have a lot of media, so I think I'll save the path in db, but don't relly know how to manipulate files with code, I'll try to learn!