# In Android store image in drawable folder when i catch it from my web service.

Tags: android, image, web-services

I catch one image from my web service and show this image in my all activity. but in this way i call the service in all activity, but now i want to call web-service one time and catch the image and want to store this image in draw-able, and use this image in all other layout. how can i do.. thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Follow This Link .

[How to store images in sqlite database on click event of button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041202/how-to-store-images-in-sqlite-database-on-click-event-of-button)

In that you have to change in DownloadFile() . you have to write your image download code in that function and use for more .

Comment: any other way without database ?

Comment: Hello Mohit you can store in your sd card . can you valid for that >

Comment: hey Chintan thanks for answer, i want something like that. i want image store in my apk is it possible ?

Comment: mohit if you want to store in apk then you have to store in databse. otherwise you can store in sd card and using path you can use it.

Comment: sure than i want to store in sd card.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Now you have to just write your folder name in DownloadFile() and image name which you want to store . its very easy for you.

Comment: ok.. thanks. i will do that. i am from Ahmedabad belong from Junagadh.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Thanks you for appreciate me . by

Answer (score 1):

When you want to "save" something in Android, you want to persist data on client-side.

Android has different mechanismes for saving things:

- Shared Preferences
- Internal/external file I/O
- Database

Since you want to save an image you cannot use sharedPreferences, file I/O could be a possible but i would take a look at using SQLLite Database and BLOB-datatype for this, an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it)

Comment: any other way without database ?