# How to display images in the mysql database like photo gallery in android?

Tags: android, mysql, android-activity

Actually I am developing an android application to to store images after capturing the images from camera intent and need to display those saved images from the database?I stored the images in Blob format...

Comment: Are you saving images in local database or sending to a server ?

Comment: refer this link. Here they given the code for using blob:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041202/how-to-store-images-in-sqlite-database-on-click-event-of-button

Comment: @SharpEdge I am sending images to server and need to get those images back and display like photo gallery...

Comment: @Kottary I stored the images into server.. need to display those images like photo gallery.

Comment: @Prasanna then before sending the image to server, save it in LRU cache. Then you can use grid view to populate those images.

Comment: @Kottary I want to get those images on another button click. Thats why i am stucked in this step and also am a newbie to android.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recomended to save images into the database. The Blob format is good for storing amorphous data, but you need to do some serious tricks to convert it back into a Image format.

However, might we suggest instead to save the image on the local storage and store in the database only the identifier for the image?

Comment: But I need to store the images into the database... not in phone or sd card storage.. Thats why i used httppost to store the image.. Now I need to display that images like photo gallery...